# What is the best way to design model with many nullable properties

Tags: oop, design-patterns, model, nullpointerexception, dart-null-safety

This is one of the most annoying dilemmas in designing models in most programming languages when building a complex app and I would love to hear from others on how they deal with this issue.

Consider the following problem.
In the front end, there are 4 screens appearing consecutively

Screen 2 will only appear after Screen 1, Screen 3 after Screen 2, and Screen 4 after Screen 3.

Consider them as a step like this:

`Screen 1 > Screen 2 > Screen 3 > Screen 4`

In every screen, the user needs to input some data (maybe by filling out a form) hence I need to design a model for this.

Let's call the model that holds those data `Step`

```
// in every step, Student has to fill this model
class Step {
  final bool checklist1;
  final String checklist2;

  Step({
    required this.checklist1,
    required this.checklist2,
  });
}
```

Let's say the model owning those steps  is called `Student`

So I have 2 options I can think of:

## Option 1: Make everything step nullable

```
class Student {
  final int id;
  final Step? step1;
  final Step? step2;
  final Step? step3;
  final Step? step4;
  Student({required this.id, this.step1, this.step2, this.step3, this.step4});
}
```

### Disadvantages: unecessary null check

When we use the value of `Step`, we have to check for `null` before using the value. For instance in step 4, if we want to display the value of step 1, However, we know for sure that step 1 is NOT null at step 4. We would have to write: `student.step1?.checklist1 ?? false`. Here, we are also enforcing an arbitrary default value that is never going to be used, creating confusion for other developers.

Another option is to use force unwrapping. `student.step1!.checklist` which we know is not going to crash the app but static linter would not be happy with it and nothing really justifies if it is safe or not at compile time to use this.

Maybe we could also use a null guard method like this :

```
  final checklist = student.step1?.checklist1;
  if (checklist == null) return;
  print(checklist);
```

But this adds unnecessary boilerplate if at step 4, we use the value `student.step1.checklist1` several times, it would add significant boilerplate just to satisfy the compiler, which leads to productivity loss.

## Option 2: Create a new model for every step using Inheritance

I haven't seen anyone writing a code like this before but it is something that can solve the issue.

```
class Student {
  final int id;

  Student(this.id);
}

class StudentStep1Done extends Student {
  final Step step1;
  StudentStep1Done({required int id, required this.step1}) : super(id);
}

class StudentStep2Done extends StudentStep1Done {
  final Step step2;
  StudentStep2Done({
    required int id,
    required Step step1,
    required this.step2,
  }) : super(id: id, step1: step1);
}

class StudentStep3Done extends StudentStep2Done {
  final Step step3;
  StudentStep3Done({
    required int id,
    required Step step1,
    required Step step2,
    required this.step3,
  }) : super(id: id, step1: step1, step2: step2);
}

class StudentStep4Done extends StudentStep3Done {
  final Step step4;
  StudentStep4Done({
    required int id,
    required Step step1,
    required Step step3,
    required Step step2,
    required this.step4,
  }) : super(
          id: id,
          step1: step1,
          step2: step2,
          step3: step3,
        );
}
```

### Disadvantages:

This causes a serious problem in Serialization / Deserialization.

Let's say I receive a json data from server:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "step1": {
      "checkList1": true,
      "checkList2": "done"
    },
    "step2": {
      "checkList1": true,
      "checkList2": "done"
    },
    "step3": null
  }
```

How do I know in which of the 5 models to load this data? Maybe you could suggest I run a conditional check, like if

```
if json["step1"] == null => // Load in Student
if json["step1"] != null &&  json["step2"] == null => // Load into StudentStep1Done
if json["step2"] != null &&  json["step3"] == null => // Load into StudentStep2Done

...
```

But this loses all the benefits point of type safety since I have to hardcode the keys into strings. And also, these conditions will have to be added for every nullable field, which will make the code lengthy and complex.

I would appreciate a well-detailed answer, but even a redirection to an article, or keyword I should search for or a book, would be of great value since I don't know what is the technical name of this topic.

I wrote the example in Dart but it would be even better if some answers are in other programming languages highlight specific language features that tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that it is possible to return `false` value when screen is not filled in:

```
student.step1?.checklist1 ?? false
```

So we can just return fallback values if values are not filled in in screens. I've made an example via C# but I've added comments what data structures you can use in Java when you will convert code from `C#` to `Java`.

So let's model step where user is filling data. Class would have name `Step`:

```
public class Step
{
    public bool _checkList;

    public string _checkList_2;

    public Step(bool checkList, string checkList_2)
    {
        _checkList = checkList;
        _checkList_2 = checkList_2;
    }
}
```

Then we need something like `Carousel` where user goes over the fillable pages:

```
public class Carousel
{
    public int _currentScreeeNumber = 0;

    public Dictionary<int, Step> _screens = new Dictionary<int, Step>(); // It would be
    // in Java Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>(){{ put("cat", 1);}};


    public bool ExistsScreen(int screenNumber) 
    {
        return _screens.ContainsKey(screenNumber);
    }

    public Step GetScreenByNumber(int screenNumber) 
    {
        if (!ExistsScreen(screenNumber))
            throw new ArgumentException("There is no such screen with sucn number");

        return _screens[screenNumber];
    }


    public void Add(int screenNumber, Step step) 
    {
        _screens.Add(screenNumber, step);
    }
}
```

and our user form where user fill some data, e.g. for 4 pages. Class name is `UserForm`:

```
public class UserForm
{
    public int[] _steps;
    public Carousel _carousel;

    public UserForm(int overallSteps)
    {
        _steps = new int[overallSteps];
        _carousel = new Carousel();
    }


    public void FillInSurvey() 
    {
        // imitation that user is filling data
        for (int i = 0; i < _steps.Length; i++)
        {
            _carousel.Add(i, new Step(true, "screen is filled with info"));
        }
    }

    public Step ShowInfoFromScreen(int screenNumber) 
    {
        if (_carousel.ExistsScreen(screenNumber))
            return _carousel._screens[screenNumber];

        return new Step(false, "screen is NOT filled with info");
    }
}
```

Pay attention to method `ShowInfoFromScreen(int screenNumber)`. It is possible to call this method from HTML and it will return filled data or some fallback data if user have not filled data for that screen.